# how to allow duplicate keys in Hashmaps Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I need a kotlin code for a hashmap that allows duplicate keys

```
class HashMap<K, V> : MutableMap<K, V>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What are you trying to build? Why does it require duplicate map keys?

Comment: Maps cannot have duplicate keys. Use a `MutableList<Pair<K, V>>` or a `MutableMap<K, MutableList<V>>` instead.

Comment: I have a key ,value list that has duplicate keys

Comment: Map the values of duplicate keys to a list value associated with common key, then.

Comment: @Tenfour04 can you explain ? the list is something like this {test:physics,test:math,quiz:lab}

Comment: When you look up one of the duplicate keys (e.g. "test" in your example) in your ‘map’, what result do you want back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your keys and values are both Strings, you could make a `MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>>`.

```
val eventsBySubject = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()

// Adding a value "physics" for key "test":
eventsBySubject.getOrPut("test", ::mutableListOf).add("physics")

// Getting all the values for a key "quiz":
val quizzes: List<String> = eventsBySubject["quiz"].orEmpty()

// Removing a single value "lab" for key "test":
eventsBySubject["test"]?.remove("lab")
```

Comment: You could also make the key type a MutableSet, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 9):

What you want can be achieved with a `List` that contains `Pair`s:

```
val mapWithDuplicateKeys = listOf(
            KEY1 to VALUE1
            KEY1 to VALUE2
            KEY2 to VALUE3
    )
```

Or simply by adding to the list:

```
val mapWithDuplicateKeys=mutableListOf<Pair<String,String>>()
mapWithDuplicateKeys.add(KEY1 to VALUE1)
mapWithDuplicateKeys.add(KEY1 to VALUE2)
mapWithDuplicateKeys.add(KEY2 to VALUE3)
```

Checking for containing entries would be like:

```
mapWithDuplicateKeys.any { it.first==KEY1 && it.second==VALUE1 } //true
mapWithDuplicateKeys.any { it.first==KEY1 && it.second==VALUE3 } //false
```

Removing entries would be like:

```
mapWithDuplicateKeys.removeIf { it.first == KEY1 && it.second == VALUE1 }
```

Retrieving entries would be like:

```
val valuesMatchingKEY1 = mapWithDuplicateKeys.filter { it.first== KEY1 }.map{it.second}
```

Of course you could always make a new class and wrap all the above functionality with simple methods :)